# How to log all errors in debug.log instead of on the page for WordPress

Tags: php, wordpress, logging

For some reason, showing errors/warnings on my website stops some functions from working. So, I just want to show all errors in DEBUG.log instead of on the pages. I did the below in wp-config.php but it didn't work. Any other ideas?

```
define( 'WP_DEBUG', true );
define( 'WP_DEBUG_LOG', true);
define( 'WP_DEBUG_DISPLAY', false );
```

Comment: check if error_reporting is on. `ini_set('display_errors', 1);
ini_set('display_startup_errors', 1);
error_reporting(E_ALL);`

Comment: Where do I check? There're no such params in wp-config.php

Comment: THis page, https://digwp.com/2009/07/monitor-php-errors-wordpress/ asks me to have like @ini_set('log_errors','On') on wp-config so I tried but doesn't work. No log in php-errors.log which I created.

Comment: add this `ini_set('display_errors', 1); ini_set('display_startup_errors', 1); error_reporting(E_ALL);` before `define( 'WP_DEBUG', true );`

Comment: Just in case: the file should be called `debug.log` (lowercase), not `DEBUG.log` (although that might not matter on some OSs). Also, make sure the file is writable by PHP.

Comment: Also check the permissions on `wp-content` and `debug.log` (if already created) and verify that they are writable by web server (e.g. apache2) process.

Comment: Mine is DEBUG.log as generated by WP. Yes, I can see the log. But not the log I'm expecting. It's ok, I'll keep trying